# Checking read lines with some regexes

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to check a line for few conditions, like i.e.

1. Is line empty
2. Does line contains begin of multiline comment
3. Does line contains begin of multiline comment + anything else except spaces
4. Does line contains end of multiline comment
5. Does line contains end of multiline comment + anything else except spaces
6. Does line starts with a single line comment

As for regexes I've come up with some:

1. `"^\\s*$"`
2. `"/\\*+"`
3. `"[^\\s]/\\*+"`
4. `"\\*/+"`
5. `"[^\\s]\\*/+"`
6. `"^//"`

But I'm not sure if they do what I think they do. Could someone take a quick look and tell me if they ok, and if the way I'm trying to do the checking is the right one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2: would match one or more stars anywhere on the line. I'd write it `"^\\s*\\*"`.

3: `"^\\s*\\*\S+$"`

4: no need for the `+`

5: it only allows one character before the multiline end, and the `+` is not needed (as in 4.). I'd write it `"^\\S+\\*/\\s*$"` (to account for spaces after the final `/`).

6: it is OK if you explicitly disallow spaces before it, otherwise write `"^\\s*//"`.

You have other problems, though! Writing a regex for multiline comments is tricky, it can be done but it is tricky nonetheless.

Comment: thanks, few questions though. As for 1, I would read yours as starts with space followed by zero or more spaces and a star (because you've escaped it so it doesn't mean anymore zero or more but literally star). As for 2 - why does it have to start with a space? and and with non-space character?

Comment: So do I understand that mine 1 does what is intended to do?